# Fetch map center when i scroll through the map in android

Tags: android

I have a mapview in my app. My requirement is each time when I scroll through the map, I have to fetch the current center point of the map. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getMapCenter%28%29)

getMapCenter()

Comment: getMapCenter() always returns the center point of the map...at (0,0) location...If i take australia and zoom the map...i wont get the current center point as the right one since getMapCenter() always returns to the same value..hope u understood my requirement..

Comment: Are you saying it returns 0,0 ? What are you using the emulator ?

Comment: Sorry I had made a mistake in my code..getMapCenter() works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First get a projection for converting between screen-pixel coordinates and latitude/longitude coordinates.

```
Projection P = mapview.getProjection();
```

Now you need to find the height and width of the screen in pixels and divide each by two which will given you the pixel coordinates of the center of the screen.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

GeoPoint G = P.fromPixels(metrics.heightPixels/2, metrics.widthPixels/2);
```

G is the GeoPoint of the center of your present screen.